# Extracting Realtek Bluetooth firmware from Windows drivers possible? - RTL8723DE

Tags: linux, bluetooth, reverse-engineer

I have a [RTL8723DE](http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=62&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) Wifi-Bluetooth module in a laptop. In Linux—in order to get Bluetooth working—it needs the Bluetooth firmware. I extracted the data `.cab` files in the Windows driver provided by the manufacturer and cannot figure out whether it is straightforward to get the firmware?

The file below seems to be the only thing in the extracted Windows driver archive that sounds similar to firmware or patch.

```
/BT_Include_X86/rtl8723d_mp_chip_bt40_fw_asic_rom_patch_new.dll
```

My laptop is running Ubuntu 17.10 Linux and complains about missing firmware or patch for RTL8723DE didn’t find patch for chip id 2. So, I assumed if a firmware or patch can be dumped/extracted from Windows drivers or from Windows 10 laptop, it will resolve this and bluetooth will work.

```
Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[   12.156688] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   13.967209] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[   13.967211] bluetooth hci0: Falling back to user helper
[   13.967519] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   14.815717] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=2
[   14.815718] Bluetooth: hci0: didn't find patch for chip id 2
```

Comment: Well, that is the wifi module driver. I have that installed. It seems RTL8723DE Bluetooth firmware is needed.

Comment: I don't know the RTL8723DE, but normally a Linux driver requiring a separate firmware file includes a tool to extract the firmware file from the windows driver (or at least instructions how to do it).

Comment: Yeah. No directions. I'm hopeful Realtek will release rtl8723de firmware to rtl-bt.